Error: Not Found on App Engine after deploy of a Spring Boot App
I just deployed my Spring Boot App (kotlin language with maven) into App Engine. On the local environment it is running ok but on App Engine it gives me the following error:
App Engine Error
I tried to look into the logs on google console and the request to the swagger ui is reaching but retrieving a 404 not found error:
Google Console Logs
I saw some answers about the cloudsdk version and downgraded it but the issue still persists.
This is my appengine-maven-plugin:
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
    <cloudSdkVersion>330.0.0</cloudSdkVersion>
    <version>1</version>
    <projectId>--------</projectId>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>

So the request is getting there but for some reason this was the response, anyone has any idea what might be causing this?
